# pull data from the database with the aspx div

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

I want to get data from the database to the div structure in the below code. For example, when there are 5 records in the database will be composed of 5 pieces of panel. I am using SQL and ASPX.

Panel structure;

```
<div class="panel panel-default text-center">
    <div class="panel-heading"> 
        <span class="fa-stack fa-5x">
            <a href="#"><img src="/images/aa.png" width="100" height="125" /></a>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <h4><a href="#">Yayın Adı</a></h4>
        <p>0. Sayı</p>
        <p>0 Görüntülenme</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">OKU</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try repeater control [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zzx23804%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jQuery, it's pretty simple:

- Create a web service that exposes a function to perform the database query
- Add the ScriptMethod attribute to the function and the ScriptSerivce tag to the class
- Add the following code to your page:

  ```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '/url/to/your/service',
         success:  function(data) {
             //The data object will contain the data returned by your web service
          },
          error: function() { /*Take care of errors here*/ }
      });
  });
  ```

You could also use ajax without jQuery, but that's what I'm familiar with.

Comment: Thank you for help. I solved my problem by a different method. Asp.net done in a very simple manner as characterized in Repeater.